# Deleting from huge database

Tags: c#, mysql, innodb, delete-row, corresponding-records

I'm deleting data from database which is about 1.8GB big. (through C# app)

The same operation on smaller databases (~600MB) run without problem, but on the big one I'm getting:

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction.

Will `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` fix the problem or there is another way?

I don't think that optimizing queries is a solution, because there is no way to make them simpler.

---

I'm deleting parts of the data on conditions and relations, not all the data.

Comment: Look into adding the appropriate indexes for your delete call _or_ be sure you're using the existing indexes.

Comment: I'm also curious why this is tagged C#.

Comment: Can you batch the deletes into smaller chunks?

Comment: This was my only hope, but I checked this before posting here. :( It's tagged in C#, because the delete is running in a C# application which have to "clean" the database, and I'm curios if C# has some memory limitations for mysql operations?

Comment: You should amend your question to include (1) the delete command, (2) table schema with indexes, and (3) how much of the 1.8GB you intend to delete with the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the delete statement into smaller parts that wont timeout.
Like delete these stuff from id 1 to 1000 ,execute and commit, do the same for ids 10.000 -20.000 and etc..

Comment: If a table is poorly indexed, deleting a single row could cause timeouts.

Comment: This may be a solution, but would C# handle it? I have milion or half a million records in some tables. :/

Comment: Are you using Entity,nhibernate or just connecting straight forward?
If you are just using the plain connector then you have to do it by yourself as there's no optimization going on.

Comment: Pure C# with .NET 2.0 (it's old, but its required)

Comment: Could it also be the connector timing out? If you cant find a way to increase that timeout then i'm afraid you don't have any other option.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you were '...deleting parts of the data based on some conditions and relations, not all the data'. I would check that there are appropriate indexes on all the keys you are using to filter the data to delete.

If you were to show us your schema and where clause we could suggest ones that may help.

You should also consider splitting your delete into multiple batches of smaller numbers of rows.

Another alternative would be to do a SELECT INTO, with only the data you want to **keep** into another table, drop the original, then rename this new table.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click the table--> Script Table As --> Create To --> New query.. save the query...

Right click the table --> delete

Refresh your Database and Intellisense to forget the table and then run the script which will recreate the table and that's how you have an empty table...

Or you can simply increase the setting for innodb_lock_wait_timeout (or table_lock_wait_timeout, not sure which) if you dont want to delete all the info in the table

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a solution for me. I have different databases on different servers it is pointless to save ready queries for all.

Comment: Or you can simply increase the setting for innodb_lock_wait_timeout (or table_lock_wait_timeout, not sure which) if you dont want to delete all the info in the table

Answer (score -1):

If you're deleting all the rows in the table, use

```
 Truncate table *tablename*
```

The delete command uses the transaction log when completing the task, but truncate cleans it out without logging.

Comment: I'm deleting parts of the data based on some conditions and relations, not all the data.